# Can Ant detect if a project is closed in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ant

We're using Eclipse on a flat multi-project set-up.  Ant builders are set up on each project to create jars as needed; the ant files are used to manually kick off junit tests, create junit reports, etc.

One project is set up as a "master build" project, from which one has a convenient single ant target "test-all", which invokes the test target in all the other projects.  This works, no problem.

The challenge is, that to some developers, certain projects represent optional components that aren't relevant to their immediate work task.  So they close these projects to create some time-savings when doing things like clean and rebuild the whole workspace.  This is fine, Eclipse ignores the closed projects as intended.

Problems occur when one goes to the "master build" project, and runs the ant test-all target.  As you'd expect, it goes and tries to run the tests for *all* the projects, not just the "open" ones.

Any easy way to make the ant script smarter when running in an eclipse environment to know about "closed" projects, so I could make it ignore those?

Sort of adding an "unless=${CLOSED.UNDER.ECLIPSE}" type of ability to my ant files.

many thanks.

Comment: If ant could detect that it was running under eclipse at all, it might get you part of the way there.

Comment: Is there anything in the `.project` file that can tell you whether the project is closed? You could parse that out, using an `<exec>` task if nothing else.